# How to add different annotations on figures with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, facet-wrap

I would like to add different annotations on figures produced by facet_wrap.

I tried the below code, but the it showed error such as "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'value' not found".

```
dat_text <- data.frame(
  label = c("TRUE:FALSE = 686:324", "TRUE:FALSE = 976:34", "TRUE:FALSE = 516:494", "TRUE:FALSE = 360:650",
            "TRUE:FALSE = 351:659", "TRUE:FALSE = 440:570", "TRUE:FALSE = 645:365", "TRUE:FALSE = 151:859", "TRUE:FALSE = 542:468"),
  cyl   = c(Agricultural_land, Artificial_land, Precipitation, Protected_area,
            RiverLake, Seashore, Temperature, Volcanic_area, Wasteland)
)


z_cor <- fit01_zsize2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value_without, y = value_with, color = value))+
  geom_point(shape = 1)+
   geom_text(
     data    = dat_text,
     mapping = aes(x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = label),
     hjust   = -0.1,
     vjust   = -1
   )+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "salmon", "FALSE" = "steelblue"))+
  facet_wrap(.~variable1)+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
            axis.title=element_text(size=16))

plot(z_cor)
```

When I tried the same code without geom_text(), it worked.

---

When I could avoid the error, the new problem has come.
I pasted the figure I created. Many annotations has come in a figure.
[image]

Comment: You have specified `color = value` as a global aes. But as a column `value` is not found in `dat_text` you get an error. Make it a local aes by moving it to `geom_point(aes(color = value), ...)`. A second option would be to set `inherit.aes=FALSE` in `geom_text`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The error was avoided, but another problem was occurred. If you have time, please see new problem added in a form.

Comment: Aw. Yeah. You want one label per facet. However, in your `dat_text` dataset there is no faceting variables, i.e. `variable1`. Hence all labels are plotted in each facet. Your column `cyl` should probably be named `variable1`. Also. Make sure that you quote the values in this column which in your example code is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stefan noted, your text layer's data should reference the faceting variable:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~am) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(wt = 2, mpg = c(30, 12), am = c(0,1),
                              label = c("one note", "and another")),
            aes(label = label))
```

[image]